# KnockoutJs mapping JSON to viewmodel

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I'm having problem with binding JSON from ASP.net webform webapi to the viewmodel with KnockoutJs. There is no problem with wepapi and mapping to mappedQuickEntries.

Where did I get it wrong? Thanks.

Error:

> Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: ReferenceError: ItemPartNumb is not defined;
>   Bindings value: value: ItemPartNumb

View:

```
<div>    
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: quickEntries">
   <tr>
        <td data-bind="value: ItemPartNumb"></td>
        <td data-bind="value: ItemDescription"></td>     
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

ViewModel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var QuickEntry = function(_itemPartNumb, _itemDescription) {    
    this.ItemPartNumber = ko.observable(_itemPartNumb);
    this.ItemDescription = ko.observable(_itemDescription);        
};

function QuickEntriesViewModel () {        

    var self = this;
    self.quickEntries = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/DesktopModules/Blah/API/Data/GetTenQuickEntries',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {                
            var mappedQuickEntries = $.map(data, function (item) {
                return new QuickEntry(item.ItemPartNumb, item.ItemDescription);
            });

            self.quickEntries(mappedQuickEntries);              
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                alert('Failed');
            }
        }
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new QuickEntriesViewModel());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ItemPartNumb` vs `ItemPartNumber`

And you are using the `value`-binding instead of the `text`-binding.

http://jsfiddle.net/MizardX/9sqvk/

Comment: Hey thank for pointing that out. I made the changes. However, the table did not get created and now I have no error message.